# Using 'which' with matrices in R - 'is.element()' condition

Tags: r, logical-operators

How to use the `which()` function on a matrix so that it returns the coordinates of the matrix for which the condition is `TRUE`, with a condition that uses the `%in%` operator?

Usually, I'd just use the `arr.ind` argument of the `which()` function.

```
mat <- matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 10, data = 0)
mat[5,3] <- 7
which(mat==7, arr.ind = T)
```

This returns the row and column of each element in mat that validates the condition.

However, if the condition does not use `==` but `%in%`, this does not seem to work.

```
mat[4,7] <- 3
which(mat%in%c(3,7),arr.ind = T)
```

Same using `is.element`:

```
which(is.element(mat,c(3,7)),T)
```

How can I get the rows and columns of the matrix that validate the `%in%` condition?

Comment: Truy `sapply(c(3, 7), function(x) which(mat == x, arr.ind = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

As @akrun has mentioned in his comment you can run `sapply()` over a set of inputs to check. There is also another method that will work that helps to explain why `%in%` isn't working the same way as `==`:

When you use `==` to check a single value, R will return a matrix object, however when you use `%in%` R will return a vector of logical values (TRUE's and FALSE's)

```
> class(mat == 3)
[1] "matrix"

> class(mat %in% 3)
[1] "logical"
```

So `arr.ind=T` behaves differently because it's working on two different data types. If you would like to have the same form as `arr.ind=T` option but with `%in%` then you can convert your logical vector back into a matrix using the number of rows and columns from your original matrix:

```
> which(matrix(mat%in%c(3,7), nrow=nrow(mat), ncol = ncol(mat)), arr.ind=TRUE)

     row col
[1,]   5   3
[2,]   4   7
```

This also keep the same labelling as your `==` example.